# Prove that $G\cong H\times K$ if and only if there are homomorphisms...

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, direct-product

I have some questions for the following following exercise which came from Hungerford's undergraduate Abstract algebra An introduction 3rd edition text in chapter 9, section 1.

> Let $G$ be an additive abelian group with subgroups $H$ and $K$.  Prove that $G\cong H\times K$ if and only if there are homomorphisms
>
> $${\stackrel{\large{H}\stackrel{\large\large\pi_1}{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\large{G}}{\small\small\delta_1}}{\stackrel{\stackrel{\large\large\pi_2}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longleftarrow}}\large{K}}{\small\small\delta_2}}$$
>
> such that $\delta_1(\pi_1(x))+\delta_2(\pi_2(x))=x$ for every $x\in G$ and $\pi_1\circ \delta_1=i_H,\pi_2\circ \delta_2=i_K,\pi_1\circ \delta_2=0,\pi_2\circ \delta_1=0,$ where $i_X$ is the identity map on $X$, and $0$ is the map that sends every element onto the zero (identity) element.

First I think the homomorphic maps are as follows:  let $x\in G,$  and $x=(x_1, x_2)\in H\times K$, we define the mapps $\delta_1:H\rightarrow H\times \{e\}$ and $\delta_2:K\rightarrow \{e\}\times K$ then respectively,
$\delta_1(x)=(x_1, 0)$ and $\delta_2(x)=(0,x_2)$.

Since $\pi_i$ for $i=1,2$ are projection maps, then

$\pi_1(\delta_1(x))=x_1$,
$\pi_1(\delta_2(x))=0$,
$\pi_2(\delta_2(x))=x_2$ and
$\pi_2(\delta_1(x))=0$.  Also

$\delta_1(\pi_1(x))=x_1$,
$\delta_2(\pi_2(x))=x_2$,

In sum, $\delta_1(\pi_1(x))+\delta_2(\pi_2(x))=(x_1,0)+(0,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)=x$

Since this is an if and only if question.  In one direction, after figuring out what the explicit homomorphisms are, I am suppose to show that $G\cong H\times K$.  But in the other direction, I assume that $G\cong H\times K$, then figure out what the explicit homomorphism maps are suppose to be?Isn't the way the question is phrased just asking me to show that $G\cong H\times K$ given explicit homomorphism maps.

**If someone can tell me if my homomorphic maps are defined correctly and also how to what i need to show for the proof in both directions.**

Thank you.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thank you for the editing help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Since $\pi_i$ are projection maps"...  Are you *defining* them as the projection maps? In this part of the problem you are required to explicitly define the maps and show they have the desired properties. You are not given that the $\pi_i$ are projection maps, you must tells us what the $\pi_i$ are, just as you told us what the $\delta_j$ maps were. Moreover, you seem to be assuming that $G$ is **equal** to $H\times K$. That is not your assumption; your assumption is that $G$ is **isomorphic** to $H\times K$. It won't be hard to add the necessary corrections, but right now you have not proven that if $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$ then the morphisms with the relevant properties exist, you have only established this fact for the group $H\times K$  itself.
2. Yes, this is an if-and-only-if, so you have only done half the problem. Now you must show that *if* you have maps $\delta_1,\delta_2,\pi_1,\pi_2$ satisfying the given conditions, then you can define an isomorphism between $G$ and $H\times K$. Note that the only thing you will know about the maps is what you are told, and you are expected to use the maps and the properties listed to define the isomorphism.

---

Here is what a model solution might look like, in my opinion:

For the "only if"  direction: assume first that $G= H\times K$; we define $\delta_1(h) = (h,0)$, $\delta_2(k) = (0,k)$, $\pi_1(h,k) = h$, and $\pi_2(h,k) = k$. Then `... verify as you do that the maps have the desired properties...`, proving the claim for $H\times K$.

Now assume that $\psi\colon G\to H\times K$ is an isomorphism. Then we take the maps $\psi^{-1}\circ\delta_1\colon H\to G$, $\psi^{-1}\circ\delta_2\colon K\to G$, $\pi_1\circ\psi\colon G\to H$, and $\pi_2\circ\psi\colon G\to K$. Then `...verify that because` $\psi$ `is an isomorphism, these maps will have the desired properties as well.`

Conversely, for the "if" clause, assume we are given morphisms $\pi_1,\pi_2,\delta_1,\delta_2$ with the listed properties. We must use these morphisms to show that $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$.

Define $\psi\colon G\to H\times K$ by $\psi(g) = (\delta_1(\pi_1(g)),\delta_2(\pi_2(g)))\in H\times K$. We must now verify that (i) $\psi$ is a homomorphism; and (ii) $\psi$ is bijective.

Comment: the the $\pi_i$s are projection maps.  I am just super confused at what I am suppose to be doing in each directions.  Also, when it says homomorphic maps, is hungerford referring to both the projection maps and the $\delta_i$ maps?

Comment: @SethMai: You need to **define** them, not just say "Since". In that direction, you are given that $G\cong H\times K$, and you must define the maps. (Technically, you did not prove what you need to prove, since you actually seem to be assuming that $G=H\times K$, not merely $G\cong H\times K$). "Homomorphic maps" means "homomorphisms". He means these functions, **all** functions, are homomorphisms. I just told you what you are supposed to do in the other direction.

Comment: I think when Hungerford says $x=....$ and $x\in G$ and $G\cong H\times K$, doesn't that imply that $x=(h,k)$ for $(h,k)\in H\times K$?  So in effect $G=H\times K$?

Comment: @SethMai: I see *you* saying that. The quote you provide does not include that. If equality is meant, then the claim is false: the existence of the homomorphisms does not prove equality.

Comment: okay, after I define the mappings $\pi_i$ and $\delta_i$, and I have $(g,h)\in H\times K$, and $x\in G$, how do I show that $x=(g,h)$ given that $G\cong H\times K$?

Comment: I am getting the impression from your answer that I need to do more work to infer that $x=(g,h)$ from $G\cong H\times K$ after i have defined the relevant mappings and show that they are homomorphic and satisfied the stated properties.

Comment: @SethMai: You **cannot** "infer that $x=(g,h)$ from $G\cong H\times K$", *because it is not true*.  It doesn't take "more work", it takes inferring incorrect things. "Isomorphic" does not mean "equal". "Corresponds to under an isomorphism" does not mean "equal". You cannot assert two things are equal when all you know is that they are isomorphic. Isomorphisms don't collapse the universe.

Comment: after I define the relevant mappings and a bit of simple arithmetic, I get $\delta_1(\pi_1(x))+\delta_2(\pi_2(x))=(x_1,0)+(0,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)$ with $x=(x_1, x_2)$.  Or do I need to show the validity of why $x=(x_1, x_2)$?

Comment: @SethMai: Okay, clearly I am just talking to myself, so what is the point? For the very last time, and I will stop replying to you because there is no point in  my replying if you refuse to listen: you are assuming that $G$ is **exactly equal to** $H\times K$. You have no warrant for that assumption. You may do the problem first for that case, if you want, but you cannot just *assume* that $G$ is equal to $H\times K$.

Comment: I apologize I am frustrating you.  I think there is a subtle logical point I am not seeing.  But really thank you for you trying to explain it to me.  I really really appreciate it.