# Correct phrasing of similar question from Hungerford's graduate algebra and undergraduate abstract algebra texts.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]
The following question appeared in Hungerford's text: Abstract Algebra: An Introduction.

> Let $G$ be an additive abelian group with subgroups $H$ and $K$.  Prove that $G = H\times K$ if and only if there are homomorphisms
>
> $${\stackrel{\large{H}\stackrel{\large\large\pi_1}{\stackrel{\longleftarrow}{\longrightarrow}}\large{G}}{\small\small\delta_1}}{\stackrel{\stackrel{\large\large\pi_2}{\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\longleftarrow}}\large{K}}{\small\small\delta_2}}$$
>
> such that $\delta_1(\pi_1(x))+\delta_2(\pi_2(x))=x$ for every $x\in G$ and $\pi_1\circ \delta_1=i_H,\pi_2\circ \delta_2=i_K,\pi_1\circ \delta_2=0,\pi_2\circ \delta_1=0,$ where $i_X$ is the identity map on $X$, and $0$ is the map that sends every element onto the zero (identity) element. [google preview not available](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Abstract_Algebra_An_Introduction/zRkLAAAAQBAJ?hl=en)

The same question is in Hungerford's graduate Algebra text, in almost verbatim with the exception of the following changes: he used $\iota_{i}$ for $\delta_{i}$, and instead of $G=H\times K$, he has $G\cong H\oplus K$. [exercise 3, pg 62](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Algebra/e-YlBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=algebra+by+hungerford,+free+objects&pg=PA63&printsec=frontcover)

What I would like to know is, does it matter whether in the phrasing of one of the direction, whether it is $G=H\times K$, or $G\cong H\oplus K$, will the solution to the problem be affected in anyway?  The reasons I am asking are because

$(1)$ I understand that for a group $G$ and its finite product of abelian subgroups, if those finite abelian subgroups satisfy certain conditions, then $G$ can be written as the direct sum of those abelian subgroups and such direct sum is isomorphic to when $G$ is written as their direct product. [exercise 17.5 pg 194](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/An_Invitation_to_Abstract_Algebra/e8NPEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=an+invitation+to+abstract+algebra,+direct+sum&pg=PA194&printsec=frontcover)

$(2)$ In the direction of the problem where I have to use the homomorphic maps: $\pi_1\circ \delta_1=i_H,\pi_2\circ \delta_2=i_K,\pi_1\circ \delta_2=0,\pi_2\circ \delta_1=0,$ to show it satisfies the following theorem,

> If $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that
> $G=MN$ and $M\cap N=\{e\}$, then $G=M\times N$,

in order to show that $G=M\times N$

Thank you in advance.

Edit:  I include the solution to the similarly worded exercise from both text.  In the screenshot, the first solution is fro Hungerford's Graduate Algebra, and the second one, beginning at where it says exercise 21, is the solution for Hungerford's undergraduate abstract algebra text.
Furthermore, this question also appear in the following two books:

Algebra: abstract and concrete by Goodman, chapter 3 ex. 3.16 
Classic Algebra by Cohn Chapter 9 sec 9.6 Proposition 2

Comment: I can see two reasons for the change of notation. Either the groups in the graduate text are abelian, and then the sum notation is preferred. Or the author is introducing both the infinite direct product and the infinite direct sum, in which case you want to have different notations, but in the finite case both concepts coincide.

Comment: @mathma in both texts, the groups and subgroups are assume to be abelian.  Does that mean then with either notations, the two are isomorphic to each other, in essence, $G=H\times K\cong H\oplus K$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups#Generalization_to_sums_over_infinite_sets

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups#Infinite_direct_products

Comment: @mathma I have never seen the notation in the case of direct sum, $G\cong H\oplus K$, but for the case of product, i have seen both $G=H\times K$ and $G\cong H\times K$.  I wonder why that is.

Comment: @mathma when you say both concepts coincide, do you mean in the sense of isomorphism or equality?

Comment: for your first question when you write $G=H\times K$ it means that $G$ is really the set of tuples with first coordinate from $H$ and second coordinate from $K$, on top of this it has a group structure given coordinatewise. When you write $G\simeq H\times K$ it means that $G$ may have a different underlying set, but it is isomorphic to the direct product of $H$ and $K$ as a group.

Comment: for your second question, when I say they coincide in this case I mean both in the underlying set and in the group product

Comment: @mathma I just saw your response now.   So in the case where $H$ and $K$ are both subgroups of an abelian group $G$, and when you are talking about either their direct product or direct sum and whether either direct product/sum is $G$, is it $G=H\times K$/ $G=H\oplus K$ or $G\cong H\times K$/ $G\cong H\oplus K$?

Comment: @SethMai $(\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z,+)$ contains subgroups $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\cong (\{0,3\},+_{\text{mod 6}})=H$ and $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\cong (\{0,2,4\},+_{\text{mod 6}})=K$ right, with $H\cap K = \{0\}$ and $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\cong H\times K$, but $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\ne H\times K$. Compare however $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, this has subgroups $H'=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \{0\}$ and $K'=\{0\}\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, and $G:=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z = H' + K'$. $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \{0\}\cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z = H''$ and $\{0\}\times\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z :=K''$ and $G=H''\oplus K''$.

Comment: Maybe you should read about the internal direct sum, versus the external direct sum.

Comment: @Horizon there is such a thing as the internal direct sum.   I thought there is direct sum and coproduct, for "sums".

Comment: @Horizon Dr Google has been gracious enough to refer me to: https://planetmath.org/counterexamplesforproductsandcoproduct

Also I think there is an exercises about this in the text: Algebra Chapter 0 by  Aluffi

Comment: @Horizon I was thinking about this question again this afternoon, I notice in the forward direction ($\Rightarrow$), we can simply assume that $G=H\oplus K$.  In the backward direction ($\Leftarrow$), we have to use the homomorphic mappings an apply them to a mapping of the form $f:G\rightarrow  H\times K$ as if though isomorphism is being proved, but really, it is to show by applying those homomorphic mappings to the function $f$ that they satisfied the condition of $G=H\oplus K$ and $H \cap K = \{e\}$, so that $G=H\oplus K$.  But it is not that different from showing $G\cong H\oplus K$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as a fact that you need not care about, the category of abelian groups is also known as the category of $\Bbb Z$-modules. I say this solely in case it helps you restrict your attention to thinking about categories of $R$-modules for $R$ commutative.

Secondly, the category of $R$-modules is abelian (hence in particular the category of abelian groups is abelian). In an abelian category (or less generally, an additive category - that is to say, every abelian category is additive) finite [products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) are isomorphic to finite [coproducts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct). The notation $A\times B$ (or otherwise $A\prod B$), where $A,B$  are objects of a common category, is the product object in that category. The notation $A\oplus B$ (or otherwise $A\coprod B)$, denotes the coproduct in the category. In particular, in the case of abelian groups, these denote isomorphic objects.

Thirdly, I wasn't able to understand your second question, but I can edit this answer to include a response to that if you clarify what you are asking.

Comment: i did not understand what it means in when we are talking about direct product of finite number of the same objects, that such operation coincide with direct sum.  I did not understand specifically if it means equality or isomorphism.  I think this is the question that I was a bit unclear about....

Comment: @SethMai When you are working with a specific category, lets say the category of abelian groups $\text{AbGrp}$, you have a collection of objects, which is the class of abelian groups, and for each pair of objects $A,B\in\text{Ob}(\text{AbGrp})$ you have a collection of morphisms $\text{Hom}_{\text{AbGrp}}(A,B)$. We say that $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic objects if they are objects in the same category, such that there is a morphism $f:A\to B$ and a morphism $g:B\to A$ such that both composites $f\circ g=\text{id}_B$ and $g\circ f = \text{id}_A$.

Comment: For example, you can find $5!$ ways of giving an isomorphism in the category of sets from $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, where in the category of sets the notion of an isomorphism means a bijection, and you may recall that given a bijection you can form an inverse map as above. 

The notions of products and coproducts are notions that take place in a 'fixed common category' that just means that it doesn't make sense to take the 'coproduct = direct sum' of a topological space, and a vector space. But a coproduct of topological spaces is the disjoint union of spaces, which makes sense.

Comment: I did some google book searches:

Here it states "We leave it to the reader to show both the direct sum and the direct product are, up to isomorphism, uniquely determined by the set components $B$." 
 (https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Infinite_Abelian_Groups/Vb38GspKia8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=when+do+direct+sum+is+isomorphic+to+direct+product&pg=PA39&printsec=frontcover)...

Comment: But here: (https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Algebra_I/JcWWDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=direct+sum+is+isomorphic+to+direct+product&pg=PA141&printsec=frontcover) slightly before exercise 6.16, it states that for the case of vector spaces, they are equal.  I am not sure if they are product of different spaces, or one vector space is being decomposed  into a product of its subspaces.  

I am a bit confused when, are finite direct sum and finite direct product of the same objects, can be considered equal and when are they isomorphic to each other

Comment: @SethMai This is going to potentially sound very complicated before you think more about category theoretic concepts: when one is working in a category, and one wants the categorical product of a pair of objects, say $X$ and $Y$, then this is defined by a universal property, but the universal property only picks out 'a' product of this pair 'up-to-unique-isomorphism'. Because of this, one can give a *construction* of the product $X\times Y$, but there could be alternative constructions, each equally well worth denoting $X\times Y$, but these not being equal, but merely isomorphic.

Comment: For example, one defines the notion of a terminal object in a category $\mathcal{C}$. A terminal object $T$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is an object with the property that every other object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ has a unique morphism $T\to X$ in $\mathcal{C}$. But nowhere does this say the terminal object is unique. In particular, in the category of sets, any singleton set is a terminal object, since there is only one set map from any $X$ to any singleton set $\{a\}$. One could just call a terminal object $T$, and it is unique up to unique isomorphism.

Comment: When it comes to constructions, you may have a textbook that gives a definition of something called $V\times W$, in terms of elements, and in other textbooks they may merely define $V\times W$ in the categorical setting, which is only unique up to unique isomorphism. Any $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, but not necessarily equal to $\Bbb R^n$. But even looking at $\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^m\cong \Bbb R^{n+m}$, note that we must identify $((a_1,\dots,a_n),(b_1,\dots,b_m))$ with $(a_1,\dots,a_n,b_1,\dots,b_m)$, i.e. $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^m\ne\Bbb R^{n+m}$.

Comment: sorry for the late response.  I included screenshots to solutions to both exercises.  I also asked a similar question awhile back about the same question here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448093/prove-that-g-cong-h-times-k-if-and-only-if-there-are-homomorphisms
but more on the solution. Due to the differences in wording between both texts, it caused me no ends of confusion.  If you see that post and what Arturo wrote, I think his suggested solution outline is slightly different from the ones in both solutions in the screenshot.....

Comment: the difference in wordings motivated me to ask whether under what situation are direct sum and direct products for finite objects are different or consider the same.  I also found under entry 8.8 here: https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Handbook_of_Mathematics/RkepDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=direct+sum+is+the+same+as+direct+product+for+vector+spaces&pg=PA816&printsec=frontcover
which I am not sure what it means in the case of groups.  I am not sure if this is an issue i should be worry about at this moment of my math education since i not that familiar with category theory yet.

Comment: @SethMai Despite it being the case that $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2\cong \Bbb R^4$, via any number of isomorphisms, for example by $((a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2))\mapsto (a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)$ it is not at all true that $((a_1,a_2),(b_1,b_2))=(a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2)$. Similarly, even though $(\{1,-1\},\times)\cong C_2\cong (\Bbb Z/2,+)$, it does not follow that elements of these are equal.

Comment: That link you give to the handbook is only telling you that given a specific *construction* of the product and coproduct (= direct sum) in the category of groups, that these are indeed equal, but as I mention in a previous comment, any object isomorphic to the product, or isomorphic to the coproduct, are equally well deserving of being called a product or coproduct.

Comment: I feel there is something subtle that I am failing to distinguish between coproduct vs direct sum in relation to isomorphism with direct product in the case of finite number of groups.  When I learn more category theory or more advanced algebra, will I get these things sorted out.  Also, for most mathematicans, is this something they are aware of if their research intersect in any ways remotely with algebra?

Comment: or should I start a new post and ask clarification in a separate question. I am not sure how productive this will be since I am only starting to learn category theory on my own, and I am reading Conceptual Mathematics by Lawvere and Schanuel.  I don't think that book will prepare me to really understand a lot of answers on this site having to do with category theoretic language.

Comment: @SethMai I think this will become very clear to you when you get more exposure to category theory and/or advanced algebra, yes. Many early students avoid the issue by just claiming things are isomorphic whenever they aren't sure if its an equality or only an isomorphism. Additionally, many people will say 'canonical' isomorphism, even when that makes no sense (beyond it being the most natural isomorphism in some obvious 'human' way). If you ponder on my 'terminal object' comment above, you might realise what is going on with products and coproducts, even if at first sight it seems irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think you should make a new post, since its something that people have told you how to reconcile already, and you'll just hear more of the same. In particular, Arturo Magidin is correct in all his comments to you, in the linked thread (even if he is far too impatient from my perspective).

Comment: Try pondering on the following: 1) There may be many isomorphisms between two objects, 2) isomorphic objects need not be equal, 3) Objects defined by universal properties are only defined up to unique isomorphism, 4) Products and coproducts are defined by universal properties, 5) Sometimes a construction is given for a representative of an isomorphism class,

Comment: 6) In the category of groups, a construction can be given for a product and coproduct, such that these *representatives* are equal in the finite case, 7) In the category of groups, a finite product of a collection of groups, is isomorphic to the finite coproduct of these collection of groups.

Comment: thank you so much for all your detail answers.  I think I will just stick to $G=H\oplus K$ for the quesiton.   Also, I hope that in time, I can be able to recognize when it is isomorphism or equality when it comes to direct product vs and direct sums/coproduct.

Comment: As for Arturo not having patience....  I think I can take a lot of blame for that.  I did not told him the same question appears different in a different text by Hungerford and also I did not understand what was the point of my own confusion as well as when I responded to his comments, I did not know he already provide a suggested answer.